# The logic behind the ALL function from SQL. I need some explanation behind the logic of W3 School statement regarding ALL function

Tags: sql, function, select

On W3 School they say:

> The following SQL statement lists the ProductName if ALL the records in the OrderDetails table has Quantity equal to 10. This will of course return FALSE because the Quantity column has many different values (not only the value of 10):
> `SELECT ProductName  FROM Products WHERE ProductID = ALL (SELECT ProductID FROM OrderDetails WHERE Quantity = 10);`
> [image]
> Source:https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_any_all.asp

I am wrong if I say is returning FALSE because:

1. The ProductID is compared with a bunch of different ProductID (ProductID is unique and can't be equal with all different ProductID's returned by the query `SELECT ProductID FROM OrderDetails WHERE Quantity = 10`)
2. In the WHERE clause ProductID is taken one by one and compared with ALL and have to be equal with all ID's from the list returned in subquery. And are many in the list because many are equal with 10.
3. Is not FALSE because what they say in that quote.

Is my logic right?

Comment: W3*ools... is all I say.

Comment: `SELECT ProductName  FROM Products WHERE ProductID = ALL (SELECT ProductID FROM OrderDetails WHERE Quantity = 10);` doesn't make any sense as a query. It will compare the ProductId from the left hand side with all the ProductId from the sub query and only return true if all the comparisons match. i.e. it will only return rows if there is only one distinct Product in OrderDetails that has Qty of 10 or no such rows  (not at all as their explanation says)